# momentary switch using microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pic, switches

I have a battery charger that requires two presses of the switch to enter charge mode and I'd like to permanently connect it to my camper's batter and have it start charging every time I connect to a hookup.

Here's a guy that's managed it and demonstrated on YouTube but I've no idea what the IC is or how he's implemented it.

[YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJtitHMMuZo)

If anyone can give some more details I'd be most grateful.

TIA

Comment: Can't you ask the person in the YouTube comments?

Comment: A couple of people have already done that with no response. You'd think he'd reply wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The microcontroller is just emulating the button presses.

1. Determine the voltage used by the existing circuit (button and the IC it's connected to). Probably 3.3 or 5 VDC.
2. Determine the button's sense, i.e. depressed is a high or a low signal?
3. Find where this signal goes. Connects to which pin of the existing microcontroller/IC?
4. Buy any cheap microcontroller that will operate on the same voltage found in step 1.
5. Program the microcontroller to have a delay at start up (to give everything (the charger circuitry) time to initialize), then output a pulse with the correct sense (found in step 2), wait for a short delay, and output another pulse.
6. Connect the microcontroller to the existing circuit's voltage and ground (video shows across the tantalum (polarized) capacitor).
7. Connect the pin where you are outputting the pulses to the pin found in step 3. Or just connect to the output pin of the button (as seen in the video).
8. Turn the power on and smile.

That's the gist of it. The two pulses should last long enough to be seen as a button press by the existing microncontroller or circuit (probably at least 100ms).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MOSFET transistor in place of a button. When a small voltage is given to the gate port of the mosfet (small voltage from digital I/O pin) current can pass through the transistor.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for or if it would solve your problem.